# How to call a variable in include function in blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have tried to call a variable in include function in `laravel` but  I am getting error. can anyone give the solution. 
I tried this above way.

```
@include('admin/$page')
```

Comment: do you want to pass the variable to included blade file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you have passed `$page` to your blade template then the only thing you need to do is:

```
@include("admin/{$page}")
```

Pay attention to double quotes.